# Can we use potassium iodide as pH meter electrode storage solution.? If not then why?

Tags: equipment

If KCl is not available can KI be used to store pH probe meters? Both are potassium salts.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\ce{KCl}$ is used due to the diffusion coefficients of both ions being similar, but I might be wrong though.

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider You are *correctly* pointing to Hittorf's ion transfer numbers (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_transport_number).